# Wingpanel freezes during Discord voice calls

Tags: release-juno, release-hera

I've searched for a fix and it seems like this was last addressed a few years back, and was supposed to have been patched? But every time I join a voice call in Discord, the top bar freezes. Time doesn't change, can't access launcher, the color of the bar doesn't change according to the app, etc. I have to restart it via terminal every time and it only lasts a minute at most before it freezes again. As soon as I hang up though, everything works again.

Is this a known issue and is there a fix for it? I'm really tired of having to kill wingpanel in terminal every few minutes if I need to open another app while calling my friends. This happened when I was on juno and continues to happen in hera.